# How to publish a mongodb array length as an additional collection field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongodb collection with the following fields:

- `_id`
- `name`  (string)
- `[items]`  (array of string)
- `secret`  (boolean)

I want to publish the all the _id, name fields and the item array length only (excluding the secret field) where the secret field is true.

I have read somewhere that I can add additional document properties in my find query, but my google foo does not work.

Here is what my publish method looks like **without** the additional `items_count` property:

```
Meteor.publish("all_items", function() {
    return myItems.find(
                 {secret: true},
                 {fields:
                   {_id:1,name:1}
                 });
        });
```

How can I create an additional field from the `[item]` length in my publication?

**EDIT**: it seems that I need to use an `aggregate` function and the `$project`operator. And it is not supported by meteor.

Can anyone confirm this to me (i.e. it is the only option and it is not supported)?

Comment: _"it is the only option [...] ?"_ No. You can use map-reduce. Is it supported by Meteor ?

Comment: I am still not clear on high level functions map reduce. I would need to learn first especially reduce, I don't get it properly. In the meantime, I'll try the solution provided by @n9code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add `aggregation framework` support to `Meteor`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate), and then use a simple aggregation pipeline with `$project` stage as you mentioned, like to following:

```
myItems.aggregate(
    [
       {$match: {secret: true}},
       {$project: {_id: 1, name: 1, items_count: {$size: '$items'}}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Nice solution, but for meteor, you should mention that to be published it requires to 1) store the aggregate result array in a variable, 2) iterate on each of the items of the returned array, 3) in the loop, add them one by one to your publication using this.added('nameOfClientCollection', Random.id(), {your: databaseFields}); 4) make the publication available using this.ready(). I validate the answer